# JavaScript + ASP.Net web service proxy classes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I'm about to re-write the front end of an application currently written in Silverlight using JavaScript (with use of the Dojo toolkit).  The current Silverlight application uses WCF webservices hosted on the server to get / send data.  Visual Studio created all of the proxy classes for the Silverlight application, enabling Intellisense and so on.

Is there any way to achieve this in Visual Studio when using JavaScript?  i.e. is there any way to have Visual Studio build proxy classes from the WCF web services so Intellisense will work?

Also, the WCF services / Silverlight app were written a while ago.  Has anything replaced WCF as the logical web service back end for this sort of application - I've read a bit about Web API and SignalR - do they offer any advantages over sticking with the existing WCF services and just periodically polling them for data?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: *- I've read a bit about Web API and SignalR - do they offer any advantages over sticking with the existing WCF services and just periodically polling them for data?* --> SignalR with WebAPI -or sticking with WCF- will eliminate the need for polling. You can instead push the data from the server to the client if WebSockets is supported on your Web Server. If it isn't supported, you can use XSockets.NET, for example.